# How can I set up Google Authenticator (TOTP) for 2-step verification on my Google account?

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth, google-authenticator

I want to set up a TOTP tool like Authy (or Google Authenticator, 1Password's TOTP support, etc) on my Google account, which works the same way as [Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator).

However, I can no longer find Google Authenticator as an option for my security settings. On My Account, when I click *2-Step Verification*, the only options I get are *Security Key*, *Google Prompt*, and *Text message or voice call*.

[Authy's guide to Gmail](https://authy.com/guides/gmail/) shows what looks like an older UI – I don't see anything similar when I'm looking at my account's security settings. Here's what I do see:

[image: Screenshot of "signing in" section of my security settings]

[image: Screen of 2-step verification page]

Can I still set up TOTP for my Google account? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome. The way you phrase your question makes it off-topic for the site. Please try editing it. In any case your best bet is [Authy Support](https://support.authy.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Answer (score 4):

One thing I suggest to try is to set up 2-factor with your phone number first. It could be that Google only allows TOTP once a phone number is associated with the account as a back-up.

Comment: I had to do this:

1. Set up 2FA with phone number (using SMS)
2. Set up 2FA with Google Authenticator app
3. Remove phone number from my account

Comment: I don't even see "use your phone to sign-in" or "2-step-verification" I just see "password" :(